# How to verify textbox present in selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to automate a manual script to check the presence of a textbox field in selenium.
Can u please help me in finding the same.

Comment: Use assertElementPresent(). Can you please give some code of your site? It would be easier to help you in location of this field.

Comment: No, I want to verify that certain element should be only textbox .
like I have for Amount field . It should not be dropdown or checkbox etc
So how to check that element with certain locator is a textbox .
How to write code for it in java(selenium testng)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`assertElementPresent` along with path of element.`xpath=(//input[@type='text'])` or just `//input[@type='text']`

It will check whether element with type text is present on Page or not

Comment: What if I have more than one textbox on the page . If I want to check that this particular field should be textbox and this be not ? any help

Comment: sorry, not check-box, its text box

Comment: Probably this field has got any attribute and you can locate it by id or name. Then you can use assertElementPresent("//input[@name='name-of-this-field' and @type='text']").

Comment: Yes, this will be the better solution to go with name and type...It will be great if you provide HTML of element you are trying to identify

Comment: Thanks a Lot Rohit And Faramaka

Comment: Thank You Rohit and Faramaka ,Your help was really very useful .

Answer (score 0):

assertEditable|//input[@name='name-of-this-field' and @type='text']

instead of assertElementPresent

this will fail if the field is not a text box or text area...